# jQuery replace anchor tag with href url in textarea

Tags: jquery, anchor

How do I replace anchor tags in a string with only their links as text.

Actual:

```
var text = "This is a test article with links which need to be replaced. < a href=" http://local.mysite.com/test/f/english-as-a-second/p/addpost">local.mysite.com/.../addpost< /a> Another link which needs to be replaced < a href=" http://local.mysite.com/test/f/match">local.mysite.com/.../match < /a>"
```

Desired Result:

```
This is a test article with links which need to be replaced. http: //local.mysite.com/test/f/english-as-a-second/p/addpost
```

Another link which needs to be replaced http: //local.mysite.com/test/f/match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are allowed to use jQuery, this works.

```
var str = 'This is a test article with links which need to be replaced. <a href=" http://local.mysite.com/test/f/english-as-a-second/p/addpost">local.mysite.com/.../addpost</a> Another link which needs to be replaced <a href=" http://local.mysite.com/test/f/match">local.mysite.com/.../match </a>';
var $str = $('<div/>').html(str);
$str.find('a').each(function ()
{
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).attr('href'));
});
var result = $str.text();
console.log(result);
```

Special note:  Be careful about the space between `<` and `a`.  You have `< a` which won't always be recognized as correct html.  Same thing in your `< /a`.

Comment: NP.  I did something similar recently where we had people copy/pasting into a text area and I needed to deal with them having html code in the pasted data.  This trick came in very handy.